# React: update state only once, when another state reaches certain value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, promise, react-custom-hooks

Here's my code https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-cannon-lvse23?file=/src/App.js

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

function useAsyncState() {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("idle");

  function trigger(value) {
    setStatus(`sending ${value}`);
    setTimeout(function () {
      setStatus("done");
    }, 1500);
  }

  return [status, trigger];
}

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const [status, trigger] = useAsyncState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "done") {
      setValue(value - 1);
    }
  }, [status, value]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>
        status: {status}
        <button onClick={() => trigger(value)}>send & decrement</button>
      </p>
      <p>
        value: {value}
        <button onClick={() => setValue(value + 1)}>increment</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have some kind of async action wrapped into a custom hook `useAsyncState` (simplified version of some real hook from my dependencies).

The problem is, I want to update `value` only once, when async action turns into `done` state.

However, changing state rerenders the component and since `status` is still `done`, `value` changes again, leading to endless loop of decrementing.

Also, action can be triggered again and I want to decrement value, when it's `done` again.

If I had an original Promise, I could do it in `then` callback, but I have only a hook like this.

Also, using `useEffect` delays `value` update to the next render, so it takes two renders to show decremeneted `value`. It's not a big deal, but it would be nice to do it in single render.

Is it ever possible to do it nice with such a custom hook? Or using raw Promises is the only way?

Comment: You can remove `value` from deps array and use functional update: `setValue((value) => value - 1);` in your useEffect hook.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Functional Update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) instead:

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to setState. The function will receive the previous value, and return an updated value.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (status === "done") {
    setValue((prevValue) => prevValue - 1);
  }
}, [status]);
```